# array alignment of 3 bits

Tags: c++, alignment, bit-fields

I have a struct that contains a 3-bit field.

```
struct A {
  unsigned char a:3;
};
```

I'd like to have an array of `struct A` that each element only takes 3 bits instead of a whole byte.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: `a` uses 3 bits.  You still have the rest of the `unsigned char` in your `struct`

Comment: _"Is there anyway to do it?"_ No there isn't. Smallest unit yo can refer to is an `unsigned char` which actually is representing a `byte`

Comment: But you can create array of struct with 3 * 8 bits.

Comment: *"Is there anyway to do it?"*  So say you could do this.  What would `sizeof(a)` give you?  three-eighths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best way would be to store 24 bits in each struct, then you have 8 x 3 bit entities in each struct.  You can use bitwise manipulation to access each entity of 3 bits within the struct of:

```
struct A {
  unsigned char a[3];
};
```

Then you have no wasted space when you create arrays, etc.  However, you will waste any 3 bit entities that are not used, maximum 7 of them vs possible minimum of 0 (no wastage).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. `a` takes 3 bits, but `A` would take at least sizeof(char).

By the way, this is exactly why you can have bit fields as struct members, but can't have bit variables - as, say, function local variables. Minimally addressable unit is one byte.